# In Ruby language, how can I get the number of lines in a string?

Tags: ruby, string, count

In Ruby language, how can I get the number of lines in a string?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

There is a `lines` method for strings which returns an `Enumerator`. Call `count` on the enumerator.

```
str = "Hello\nWorld"
str.lines.count # 2

str = "Hello\nWorld\n" # trailing newline is ignored
str.lines.count # 2
```

*The `lines` method was introduced in Ruby 1.8.7. If you're using an older version, checkout the answers by @mipadi and @Greg.*

Comment: "Hello\nWorld\n".lines.to_a # => ["Hello\n", "World\n"]

Note, the newlines are not ignored, they are included with the line.

Comment: Greg, I meant the very last newline is ignored for the purposes of counting number of lines.

Comment: @Andrew, you're right. For Ruby 1.8.6 and prior versions, you'd have to use `count`, `each`, `each_line`, `split` or one of the many other ways as suggested by @mipadi and @Greg.

Answer (score 8):

One way would be to count the number of line endings (`\n` or `\r\n`, depending on the string), the caveat being that if the string does *not* end in a new line, you'll have to make sure to add one to your count. You could do so with the following:

```
c = my_string.count("\n")
c += 1 unless c[-1,1] == "\n"
```

You could also just loop through the string and count the lines:

```
c = 0
my_string.each { |line| c += 1 }
```

Continuing with that solution, you could get really fancy and use `inject`:

```
c = my_string.each.inject(0) { |count, line| count += 1 }
```

Comment: That is the most unnecessarily complex solution I've seen in tens of minutes

Comment: @David: It's one line of code. `String#lines` isn't in all versions of Ruby, as noted in another answer.

Answer (score 7):

`string".split("\n").size` works nicely. I like that it ignores trailing new-lines if they don't contain content.

```
"Hello\nWorld\n".split("\n") # => ["Hello", "World"]
"hello\nworld\nfoo bar\n\n".split("\n").size # => 3
```

That might not be what you want, so use `lines()` as @Anurag suggested instead if you need to honor all new-lines.

```
"hello\nworld\nfoo bar\n\n".lines.count # => 4
```

Comment: IO#readlines does this without all the mess, but the above is basically what it does (minus the size/count method)

Comment: Except that the OP wants the number of new-lines in a String, not a file.

Answer (score 2):

`"hello\nworld\nfoo bar\n\n".chomp.split("\n",-1).size # => 4`

`String#chomp` gets rid of an end of line if it exists, and the -1 allows empty strings.

Answer (score 1):

given a file object (here, in rails)

```
file = File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'lib', 'file.json'))
file.readlines.count
```

returns the number of lines

IO#readlines performs a split method on strings (IOStrings in this case) using newlines as the separator

Comment: ** to do the above in rails, something like this ("  config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]") must be added to config/application.rb

Answer (score 1):

This will not count blank lines:

```
string.split("\n").select{ |line| line != "" }.size
```